# is there any library support RSASSA-PSS with EMSA-PSS encoding technique and certificate validation..?

Tags: c++, openssl, shared-libraries, rsa, digital-signature

i need to sign the data using RSASSA-PSS with EMSA-PSS encoding .. openssl does not support this algorithm .can any tell me  is there any other open source libraries available to do this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) mentiones PSS and EMSA.

Comment: thanks for your reply. it is basically fro .net applications right..? will it support c++ also

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL supports RSA-PSS (http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkeyutl.html#RSA_ALGORITHM), as well as other libraries (BouncyCastle should do that as well).

Comment: i am not much awre of Openssl. i too saw PSS is available but they didnt mention it is using "EMSA-PSS" encoding. i guess it uses EMSA PKCS1 encoding..

Comment: EMSA stands for Encoding Method for Signature Appendix, and PSS is short name for the scheme of such appendix as well as signature scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Have look here:
http://fixunix.com/openssl/526614-signing-verifying-messages-rsassa-pss.html
I haven't try this implementation, but I have one of my own that looks like this one, and it's perfectly working